# Wired Network refuses to connect (Ethernet / Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: networking, ethernet, realtek

Getting the error message "Activation of network connection failed"

Running `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` gave this answer :

```
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions RTL8111/8168/8411 OCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1734:118d]
    Kernel driver in us: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

`dmesg | grep r816`

```
[1.218395] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[1.218415] r8169 0000:07:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[1.219124] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: RTL8168d/8111d at 0x (ptrval), 00:26:9e:e4:e5:80, XID 081000c0 IRQ 24
[1.219127] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[1.281398] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: renamed from eth0
[33.724226] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: link down
[33.724249] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: link down
[35.281479] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: link up
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `dmesg | grep r816`

Comment: Edited. Clears anything?

Comment: "link up" looks very good. Mat we also see: `dmesg | grep -e etwork -e enp` If the output is lengthy, paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wT7mwyFXmN/

Comment: Btw - IF re-installing the OS would repair this problem - I can do that. Not too many files to back-up. I could than blacklist the Wi-Fi adapter to at least lessen the risk of the problem re-occurring.

However, at this point I'm not yet sure if this is OS-based or hardware-based problem to start with...

As a side question - given that I work with about 10-year-old laptop - would it make sense to refuse all automatic updates to the system? Are they a likely cause for these problems?

Comment: I doubt that reinstalling is a valid solution because, so far, we have discovered *nothing* wrong and therefore fixable. You might try selecting Airplane Mode at the Network Manager icon to take the wireless out of the problem. Historically, this chipset and driver have had some issues with autonegotiation. Please try: `sudo apt install ethtool` and follow with: `sudo ethtool -s enp7s0 autoneg off speed 100` Now is there any improvement? Finally, I doubt that updates are any significant issue. The r8169 driver is unlikely, sadly, to be updated.

Comment: Can not install ethtool as I can't get any internet connection to reach fi.archive.ubuntu.com (or other uploading site)

Says that it "Failed to fetch".

Comment: And I just put a memory stick with Ubuntu boot and selected "Try Ubuntu". The problem disappears and wired connection works in that set-up.

So it is definitely something in my OS set-up.

Means that the question is more about avoiding that problem re-occurring - can be get rid off by re-installing OS.

Comment: Then please, by all means, reinstall and let's see if it is fixed.

Comment: Well, after reinstalling it dropped back down to "Airplane Mode". However, after blacklisting Wi-Fi Adapter as you show me how to do before - this tile Wired Connection started to work as it should!